# In Python how to find a specific directory by name and walk through the files?

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

I'm wanting to walk through a directory and search for a specific folder (knowing the name=="bar") and then recursively process all files. Note,do not process the directory "notbar".  I can't seem to get the logic for finding the specific directory I need and not include the other duplicate files.

Given a general base_path = r'C:\data\foo'

How do I find "bar" and recursively walk through to process files.dat?

```
    C:\data\foo
       - notbar
           -123
             -file1.dat
           -456
             -file2.dat
             -file3.dat
       - bar
           -123
             -file1.dat
           -456
             -file2.dat
             -file3.dat
```

Comment: have a look at glob...
from glob import glob
matched_files = sorted(glob(base_path + r"\bar\\*\file*.dat"))

Comment: I don't think the duplicate answer provided is the same issue . I understand how and ability to use os.walk but not how to find and only process files in the specified directory.  

If dir="bar" then process files.dat. but i'm probably missing something simple

Comment: Yes I had a well written answer but the question was closed so quickly I didn’t get a chance to post!

Comment: @geometrikal thanks  I asked a new question...   maybe you can post there.
 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139977/using-python-os-walk-how-to-check-for-directory-name-and-only-process-those-file)