# Using python os.walk how to check for directory name and only process those files (recursively) in the specific directory?

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

I'm using os.walk to run through directory "foo".  I want to process .dat files but how to check for a directory name and only process the specific directory?

If dir="bar" then process files.dat. Do not process "notbar". I'm probably missing something simple

```
 C:\data\foo
       - notbar
           -123
             -file1.dat
           -456
             -file2.dat
             -file3.dat
       - bar
           -123
             -file1.dat
           -456
             -file2.dat
             -file3.dat
```

this finds all .dat files....

```
    for (root, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(base_path):
        print('Found directory: {0}'.format(root))
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(".dat"):
                print(filename)
```

Comment: `os.walk(fbase_path + '/bar')`?

Comment: To add to @juanpa.arrivillaga, use `os.walk(os.path.join(base_path, "bar"))` for compatibility with multiple OS (windows uses \ and unix /, not our problem to deal with that)

Comment: That is not really the option, this is a simplified example. The user will specify a root directory and not the path to the known folder name.

Comment: @Seraf I would personally recommend the nicer `pathlib` instead of `os.path`, so then it's just `Path(base_path) / 'bar'`

Comment: @rdebruyn so, there is some directory *somewhere* called `bar`, that is all you know?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes. There will be always be a directory in the structure with a known name ie "bar"

Comment: Well, then you can first find `bar`, then just walk again from `bar`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it does look better, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

`glob` is really good for this. It returns all the files that match a certain pattern.

There is a [reference](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/) for the patterns, but the most useful are:

- `*` matches everything except path slashes (`\` for windows, `/` for mac / linux)
- `**` matches zero or more directories

In your example, you want to find the `.dat` (`*.dat`) files in any sub-directory (`*`) of a sub-directory (`bar`) inside a base path `base_path`. To get these files we can write

```
from glob import glob

filenames = glob(base_path + "\\bar\\*\\*.dat")
```

It is better to use `os.path.join` for cross-platform:

```
from glob import glob

filenames = glob(os.path.join(base_path, "bar", "*", "*.dat"))
```

Check out the results [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=C%3A%5C%5Cdata%5C%5Cfoo%5C%5Cbar%5C%5C%2A%5C%5C%2A.dat&matches=false&tests=C%3A%5Cdata%5Cfoo%5Cnotbar%5C123%5Cfile1.dat&tests=C%3A%5Cdata%5Cfoo%5Cnotbar%5C456%5Cfile2.dat&tests=C%3A%5Cdata%5Cfoo%5Cnotbar%5C456%5Cfile3.dat&tests=C%3A%5Cdata%5Cfoo%5Cbar%5C123%5Cfile1.dat&tests=C%3A%5Cdata%5Cfoo%5Cbar%5C456%5Cfile2.dat&tests=C%3A%5Cdata%5Cfoo%5Cbar%5C456%5Cfile3.dat)

If `bar` is not necessarily the immediate sub-directory of base_path, but nested further down, you could use `**`:

```
from glob import glob

filenames = glob(os.path.join(base_path, "**", "bar", "*", "*.dat"))
```

Finally, glob will not necessarily return the files in any order. To get them in alphabetical order use `sorted(filenames)`. To get them in modified order use `sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getmtime)` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, a possible solution can be to do a second `os.walk`.  In detail

```
databasePath = ".\database"

import os

for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(databasePath):
    for dir in dirs:
    if dir == "myLabel":
        for (_root, _dirs, _files) in os.walk(os.path.join(root, dir)):
            i = 0
            print(_files)
```